# Disable Text Field Ckeditor Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a text input field that when double clicked, opens a Text Field Ckeditor Dialog, how would one stop this from happening, either by disabling the dialog itself, or possibly customizing it so it has a message in it for example?

I've looked and debugged into the code to figure out how this dialog is popping up and if i can even customize it but to no avail, any help is appreciated.

Here is the structure of the text area element:

```
<span class="TextInputWrapper">
<input class="TextInput" style="width:180px;height:26px;font-size:inherit" type="text" value="" id="20131021138501198809822047" data-cke-editable="1" contenteditable="false" data-cke-saved-name="">
</span>
```